# Redis handles are increasing after 4-5 days and causing the process to go non-responsive

Tags: redis, handle

We were facing an issue with port exhaustion on Windows Server 2019. After troubleshooting we found out that redis-server.exe was using handles more than 16000. We referred to the link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/troubleshoot-tcpip-port-exhaust
When we restarted the process, all the handles we cleared. However, after around 5-6 days we faced the same issue again, and after restarting the process the handles were cleared. After troubleshooting more we found out that the redis-server process is having filehandles as `\device\afd\` and are increasing like around 30-40 per hour. We are not able to get the exact reason why this issue has occurred. We have used process explorer to find out the handles used by the process, please refer to the below screenshot-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMU5v.png)

For redis-client info, the screenshot is attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjWfh.png)

Current client list: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWzTk.png)

I have tried to explain, with a graph how the handles are increasing day by day. Once the handles count crosses the 16000 mark, all the services using port numbers gives me an error of port exhaustion: [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40ZdR.png)

Can anyone please help to identify why this issue occurs and how to troubleshoot further as restarting the process every time the issue occurs will not work for me in long run.

Comment: Redis on Windows? Are you using https://github.com/zkteco-home/redis-windows?

Comment: Thanks Lior, 
We were trying a different link https://github.com/downloads/dmajkic/redis/redis-2.4.5-win32-win64.zip, and it worked for us for around two hours. I will try the link you have mentioned, and will update here.

Comment: Give this a try, this is an enterprise-grade native Windows port of Redis: https://www.memurai.com/get-memurai